# Looking for an iPhone app for working out chess problems

Tags: software, problems

I'm looking for an iPhone app that will allow me to set up a chess problem and work out its solution.  I've seen apps that present me with a battery of chess problems but don't allow me to set up my own.  I've also seen apps that allow me to play chess starting from the opening position.  But I haven't seen one that will allow me to configure the board as I choose.  Admittedly I haven't tried every existing iPhone app but none of the ones I've looked at allow this.

Comment: @Glorfindel I was under the impression that we weren't supposed to do product recommendations on CSE.

Comment: Smaller Stack Exchange sites often allow them, if they're reasonably scoped. I'd certainly vote to close a question like "What's the best chess app for Android?". This one is a gray area; I'd leave it open but if the community wants it closed, fine by me.

Comment: @Brandon_J I would like to see the question left open.  The fact that five others have tagged it as useful in the first few days indicates that it is of interest.  Moreover I didn't regard the answer as a recommendation but rather information about one way to do what I wanted.  I would be quite happy to have received a number different answers and tried them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only chess app on my iPhone is [Stockfish](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/stockfish-chess/id305558605), and it has a menu option Game -> Edit position where you can set up your own board. You'd also have to change the Level/Game mode to 'Two player'.

[image]

It's a free app.

Answer (score 1):

Mastersoft makes a [Chess](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/chess-pro-ultimate-edition/id561435724) app, with similar modes to Glorfindel’s answer.

I do not remember if it was free.

Comment: @RewanDemontay bizarre i hit share/copy in app store

Comment: @RewanDemontay tried the old one and youre correct it didnt work... as i said, bizarre